# Can different iOS app with the same signature share data and resource?

Tags: android, ios, security, ios7

In Android, UIDs are created and assigned on a per-package basis. We can configure our apps which with the same signature to share the same UID by modify manifest file.

I am wondering does iOS has the same mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, that it's possible because of the Sandboxing.

Read more here [iOS App Programming Guide: The iOS Environment](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/TheiOSEnvironment/TheiOSEnvironment.html) and [App Sandboxing](https://developer.apple.com/app-sandboxing/)